# Cursoring in lucene

Tags: search, lucene, cursor

How to set cursoring (for the purpose of pagination) with the search result which I obtained from lucene search. Is there any ways to do that in lucene?

Regards,
Jagadesh

Answer (score 0):

While surfing, I found http://hrycan.com/2010/02/10/paginating-lucene-search-results/. Should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method specifically dedicated to pagination: IndexSearcher.searchAfter(). In most cases this should be the best option.

Comment: It takes the last ScoreDoc of previous page, which is not always possible, specifically if users want to move to non-subsequent pages. I have used TopScoreDocCollector for pagination. If there is some better way, please share.